# Handsontable data grid js library and autoNumeric.js

Tags: handsontable, autonumeric.js

Handsontable is a JavaScript data grid library.

AutoNumeric is a Javascript library that provides live as-you-type formatting for international numbers and currencies.

If I read correctly, handsontable has a custom cell editor module. I would like to ask if anyone has managed to integrate the autoNumeric.js add-on into this module. If so, could you provide example code for the implementation.

My integration has not yet been successful.